# rsync syntax to continue failed copy data to backup

Tags: rsync

I have a 100 TB  `/data` volume and a 100 TB `/backup` volume.  In doing a `cp -rp` on all the top level folders under `/data` I got most of everything but (for example) the folder `/data/users/` has 20 TB and I only got 10 TB of it copied to /backup.

what is the `rsync` syntax to continue copying specifically `/data/users` to `/backup/users` where I

- will get any new files and folders copied
- will copy over any updated files and folders updating on /backup
- not copy files and folders I already have on /backup which are identical to that on /data
- ability to delete or not delete on /backup that which is no longer present on /data

Comment: Note that to determine that two files are identical, a program would have to read both files and compare them from start to finish. If the files differ, hhe program would then have to copy the differing bits. The rsync tool therefore simplifies the operation by overwriting any source files whose metadata differs.

Answer (score 0):

> - will get any new files and folders copied
> - will copy over any updated files and folders updating on /backup
> - not copy files and folders I already have on /backup which are identical to that on /data

The standard

```bash
rsync -a src/ dst/
```

does that. (The `-a` is just to keep file attributes and work recursively) You can add `--update` to ignore files that are newer on `dst/`; otherwise `rsync` actually the content of each `dst/` and `src/` file to only copy over changed files.

> - ability to delete or not delete on /backup that which is no longer present on /data

```bash
rsync -a --delete src/ dst/
```

From `man rsync`:

```
   --delete                 delete extraneous files from dest dirs
```